# Can't turn on WiFi - Mac Adress Unavailable on Moto E

Tags: wi-fi, motorola, mac-address

Like the title says, i'm having trouble with the WiFi. I just can't turn it on, and i think it has to do with the Mac Adress, which is "Unavailable".

I have tried the following things:
1 - Use another ROM (Cyanogenmod)
2 - Get back to stock rom
3 - Searching around the internet found some post that said it could be a problem with a deleted file ("WCNSS_qcom_wlan_factory_nv.bin") in the "persist" folder". I copied the file in that folder, but it didn't work.

Any ideas? Could be a hardware problem?

Thanks! And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are you sure that it shows unavaliable for MAC adress? Is it maybe under IP adress? Well acording to this what you wrote it is probably hardware problem.

Comment: It is under IP Adress, yes. **WiFi mac adress - Unavailable**

Comment: With out that MAC adress, you can't enable WiFi. Does Bluetooth not working also ?

Comment: Bluetooth is working